# Series expansion of a function up to linear terms

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

I have the following function:
$$f=\Sigma/\Delta$$
where
$$\Sigma=r^{2}+a^{2} \cos ^{2} \theta$$
$$\Delta=r^{2}-2 M r+a^{2}-\frac{k}{3} r^{2}\left(r^{2}+a^{2}\right)$$
and I want to obtain the expansion of $f$ up to linear terms in $M/r$ and $k r^2$. I could not get the form of the right answer which is
$$f=1+\frac{2M}{r}-\frac{kr^2}{3}$$
Does anyone have an idea as to what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: Could you show what did you get?

Comment: I only got $-\frac{3}{kr^2}$ as the leading term. Btw, I used Mathematica to obtain a series expansion of $f$.

Comment: What I also observe is that $\Delta$ has similar terms in the final answer. Like if you take out the $r^2$ from $\Delta$, you get $(1-\frac{2M}{r}-\frac{kr^2}{3}+others)^{-1}$.

Comment: Which one is the variable?

Comment: The variable is $r$, and interested at the behavior of the function at $r=\infty$.

Comment: $\Sigma$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ and $\Delta$ is a polynomial of degree $4$, then how would $\frac{\Sigma}{\Delta}$ has degree $2$?

Comment: Right. The final answer is really misleading.